# Exporting Datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF that I want to export the information to an excel spread sheet.

I am new to C# and confused about how to do this process. Does anyone have any visual examples to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XAML is:

```
<Window x:Class="ReadExcel_And_BindToDataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="490" Width="900" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,5" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="890">
                    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBox Height="30" Name="txtFilePath" Width="550" Margin="10,0,10,0" FontSize="15" Opacity="1" />
                        <Button Content="Browse Excel" Name="btnOpen" Width="120" FontSize="15" Height="30" FontWeight="Bold" Click="btnOpen_Click" />
                        <Button Content="Close" FontSize="15" Height="30" FontWeight="Bold" Name="btnClose" Width="75" Margin="110,0,0,0" Background="#FFEFE5E5" Click="btnClose_Click" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Border>
                <Label Name="txtIns" Content="View Uploaded records to DataGridView" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="dtGrid" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
        openfile.Filter = "(.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        //openfile.ShowDialog();

        var browsefile = openfile.ShowDialog();

        if (browsefile == true)
        {
            txtFilePath.Text = openfile.FileName;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            //Static File From Base Path...........
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "TestExcel.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            //Dynamic File Using Uploader...........
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(txtFilePath.Text.ToString(), 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); ;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

            string strCellData = "";
            double douCellData;
            int rowCnt = 0;
            int colCnt = 0;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
            {
                string strColumn = "";
                strColumn = (string)(excelRange.Cells[1, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                dt.Columns.Add(strColumn, typeof(string));
            }

            for (rowCnt = 2; rowCnt <= excelRange.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
            {
                string strData = "";
                for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        strCellData = (string)(excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                        strData += strCellData + "|";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        douCellData = (excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                        strData += douCellData.ToString() + "|";
                    }
                }
                strData = strData.Remove(strData.Length - 1, 1);
                dt.Rows.Add(strData.Split('|'));
            }

            dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            excelBook.Close(true, null, null);
            excelApp.Quit();
        }
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```